# Writing a text file, using parts of other text files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to figure out something that is confusing me, hope someone can help.
I have two text files with different information (these actually input files to run on Abaqus, but let's call them .txt)

- MAIN.txt

```
filler line 1
filler line 2
filler line 3
*material,name=A
density = 9
0,0
0,0
0,0
0,0
**-------------------------------------- 
FILLER LINE 5
FILLER LINE 6
FILLER LINE 7
```

**and**

- SUB.txt

```
*material,name=A
density = 10
1,1
1,1
1,1
1,1
**--------------------------------------
```

I guess it is obvious what I want to do,
write a script that creates a NEWFILE.txt which substitutes from the SUB.txt to MAIN.txt
so that my NEWFILE.txt would look like this

```
*filler line 1
filler line 2
filler line 3
***material,name=A
density = 10
1,1
1,1
1,1
1,1
**--------------------------------------**
FILLER LINE 5
FILLER LINE 6
FILLER LINE 7*
```

This is the code I have come up with, I have no issues creating a new text file, but I am unable to figure out how to swap that bit of text, from SUB.txt to the NEW.txt

```
mainFile = 'main.txt'
subFile = 'sub.txt'
outputFile = 'new.txt'
marker1 = '*material,name=A'
marker2 = '**--------------------------------------'


with open(mainFile, 'r') as f1, open(subFile, 'r') as f2, open(outputFile, 'w') as f3:
    for line in f1:
        for line2 in f2:
            if line != marker1:
                f3.write(line)
            else ?
```

Comment: well, these are input files, for Abaqus and that line that I pasted is unique. I thought of setting them as markers 1 and 2. I want to substitute the text in between those two markers.

The input file for Abaqus, the real main.inp file, has 70,000 lines of text - the co-ordinates that I want to swap 0,0 to 1,1, are wedged between those two unique lines.

Comment: My goal, since I was not clear enough, is to copy the main.txt file into a new file BUT the co-ordinates wedged between the two markers should be replaced by the ones that are in the sub.txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read the whole file `MAIN.txt` into a string, the whole file `SUB.txt` into another. Then, find the positions of `marker1` and `marker2` in the main string, and substitute everything inbetween.

```py
mainFile = 'main.txt'
subFile = 'sub.txt'
outputFile = 'new.txt'
marker1 = '*material,name=A'
marker2 = '**--------------------------------------'

with open(mainFile, 'r') as f1, open(subFile, 'r') as f2, open(outputFile, 'w') as f3:
    main = f1.read()
    sub = f2.read()
    
    start = main.find(marker1)
    end = main.find(marker2) + len(marker2)
    
    main = main[:start + 1] + sub + main[end:]
    f3.write(main)
```

Done !

Comment: Got this error

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment (in the main[start:end] line)

Comment: Thanks @KarlThornton, it works now!

If you have time, could you please explained what happened with that two extraline? I would really like to learn.
(also, my fillerline 5 is on the same line as the marker2 - would \n work to shift it one line down?)

Comment: @HansHearth sorry, I didn't know str does not support item assignment, should work now. (Without turning strings into lists !!!) (And please accept the snwer that helped you most / is the best)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a nested loop on the files and basically creating the product of the lines of the two files. This seems unnecessary. To summarize the logic needed here, a pseudocode in a way, you want to:

- Iterate the `main` file until `marker1` is reached, and write each line to the new file.
- Start iterating the `sub` file and write each line to the new file.
- Iterate again the `main` file until `marker2` is reached, ***discarding the lines***.
- Keep iterating the `main` file until the end, and write each line to the new file.

And this is directly translated to:

```py
with open(mainFile) as f1, open(subFile) as f2, open(outputFile, 'w') as f3:
    for line in f1:
        if line.strip() == marker1:
            break
        f3.write(line)

    for line in f2:
        f3.write(line)
    
    for line in f1:
        if line.strip() == marker2:
            break

    for line in f1:
         f3.write(line)
```

Comment: I tried this but it basically copied the entirety of the main.txt into the new file, and appended the sub.txt at the end.

It did not replace the co-ordinates

Comment: @HansHearth Those dang new-line characters... Please try my edit adding the `strip()` method

Comment: Thanks for that fix, but now I am getting unreachable lines (probably because of the break statements), on VS Code. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't get that in PyCharm... There are not really unreachable lines here. Sure, the first `f3.write(line)` might not be executed if the first line of the file is equal to `marker1`, but that is not the definition of *unreachable*...

Comment: that was on my end, indentation issue.

with regards to the append issue, it still persists. The new file has text that looks like all the text in the mainfile with the subfile following it. I really appreciate your time, I wish it gets sorted out

Comment: Well, I used your exact example here and it worked... Make sure that the lines of `marker1/2` are equal to the variable and between the files (amount of `-` and all that...)